# Change location of i18n folder in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular10, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translator for multi-language support. I've i18n folder inside my child folder on below path

> apps\globaltalentsystem\gts\src\app

so I get error 404 file not found for en.json and hi.json
[image]

My files are at correct level.
[image]

My **app.module.ts** has following code:

```
...  
 TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (translateLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),  
...
export function translateLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, '/globaltalentsystem/gts/src/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put your i18n folder into your assets folder

```
assets/i18n
```

Comment: no I have separate folder for child project so I can't have common assets folder.

Comment: try this because I think your defined route is not correct just add one "DOT(.)"

`export function translateLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './globaltalentsystem/gts/src/i18n/', '.json');
}`